# ng-table select filter return some label if no filter is applied

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am new to angular and exploring ng-table functionality for filters using select tag . When no filter is applied it returns empty label in select text box. Instead is there a way to show different label like "All" etc when no filter is applied?

Comment: It would be easier to understand your problem if you share some code with question

Comment: Please see example here - [link]http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-filtering-basic. See country filter, the select box is empty, I should display label "All" instead of empty select box